# Hot to improve a query based on a nested object

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS DynamoDB to store data in JSON format. The Partition key is "device" and sort key is "timestamp". I can query the table for a specific device in a range of dates. I can then filter the content by the specific endpoint (in the nested "reports" object) the application is interested in.

```
{
  "device": "AAA111",
  "attr1": "bbb",
  "reports": [
      {
         "endpoint": 1,
         "value": "23"
      },
      {
         "endpoint": 3,
         "value": "26"
      },  
      {
         "endpoint": 4,
         "value": "20"
      }
  ],
  .........
  ............
  ...........
  "timestamp": "2017-11-30T03:50:30z"
}
```

The problem I have is if for example, I want to retrieve the latest value of an specific "endpoint". So, I can retrieve the latest record for a "device" based on the latest "timestamp", but it doesn't guarantee this record will contain value for this particular endpoint (not all records contains all endpoints). To solve this I have to basically scan the latest records (in descending order) and return the first object where the endpoint is found. Also, I don't know how many records I have to retrieve to find one...

I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this... I tried with secondary indexes but this would require to duplicate the data, creating an object for each endpoint value (duplicating the common data). I would like to avoid this...

I would appreciate any hints on how to solve this issue.

Thanks
Gus

Comment: How can we determine whether the item has the latest endpoint? Do we have any attributes outside reports attributes which indicates that (i.e. any top level attribute)? So that we can use that attribute in the filter expression.

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a better solution, but I think your solution is a good one. That's how I would do it I think. If performance were a real issue you could flatten the data (so your example becomes three items, not one - then you can create a partition key of device+endpoint), but I dont think that's a good idea! As you say, GSI is an option too.